# Using flask-admin's module to query data from a model that uses One-to-Many

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I want to access the role of the logged in user and display it on the screen and I'm currently using flask-admin.

Now, for the database:

I have the following code for my users:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    *some columns*
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

The following for the roles:

```
class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and a table for their foreign values:

```
roles_users = db.Table(
    'roles_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)
```

Now I've tried `get item` and `select by index` but it didn't work. So, I'm guessing there is a more "straight-forward way" to select my values using SQLAlchemy, but are there any examples?

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy lets you access related objects through the original object's properties.
<s>To get a list of all the roles associated with a user,</s>

```
roles = logged_in_user.roles.all()
```

To get a specific role,

```
role = logged_in_user.roles.first()
```

or perhaps

```
role = logged_in_user.roles.filter_by(prop="val")
```

**EDIT**
First get the `user` object you want through an SQLAlchemy query, then read the `roles` property from `user`
Try the following:

```
def get_role():  
    username = session['username']
    with session_scope() as s:
        logged_in_user = s.query(admin.User).filter_by(username=username).first()
        return logged_in_user.roles
```

Comment: Your answer wasn't as straight forward because I tried implementing it and I keep getting `False` as a value. To be more specific I used the following lines:

`def get_role():
    username = session['username']
    with session_scope() as s:
        role = s.query(admin.User.roles).filter(admin.User.username.in_([username])).first()
        return role`

Comment: @AdamJones See my edit above. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, now I get `(False,)`, is that normal?

Comment: I would expect to see a list of `Role` objects. Is `logged_in_user.roles[0]` equal to `False`?

Comment: Yes. But I think that it means that the specific user isn't assigned to a role